# Binary Search Tree- deleting a node causes other methods errors c++

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary, nodes

I have a problem with **deleting node** from BST. I wrote a method that searches a node, that works fine, and when I'm trying to delete a leaf (an only case that I wrote so far) it causes an error *(0xDDDD...)* in printing methods. I assume that is because printing methods encounter some kind of null, but I have no idea how to fix that. Here is the code...
Deleting node by value method:

```
void deleteNodeByValue(T val)
{
    cout << "\nElement to delete: " << val << " \n";
    Node<T>* tmp = root;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (val == tmp->data)
        {
            cout << "Element found: " << tmp->data << " \n";

            if (tmp->right_child == NULL && tmp->left_child == NULL)
            {
                delete tmp;
                tmp = NULL;
                size--;
            }

            break;
        }
        else if (val > tmp->data)
        {
            tmp = tmp->right_child;
        }
        else if (val < root->data)
        {
            tmp = tmp->left_child;
        }
    }      
}
```

and tree print:

```
string to_string()
{
    stringstream ss;
    Node<T>* tmp = root;
    queue<Node<T>*> q;

    while (!q.empty() || tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            q.push(tmp);
            tmp = tmp->left_child; //debugger shows error in this place
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = q.front();
            q.pop();
            ss << "Data: " << tmp->data;
            if (tmp->left_child != NULL)
            {
                ss << " Left child: " << tmp->left_child->data;
            }
            if (tmp->right_child != NULL)
            {
                ss << " Right child: " << tmp->right_child->data;
            }
            ss << " \n";
            tmp = tmp->right_child;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
```

It also causes error in other methods like getting tree height or getting trees in order, whatever.
What should I do?

Comment: What you should do is start over. This broken code cannot be fixed in any reasonable way.There are at least two fundamental flaws: the node is deleted, but the pointer from its parent remains untouched, so iterating the BST will end up derefencing a garbage pointer [making demons fly out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon). And it only gets deleted if it's the leaf node, and nothing whatsoever happens when it's not. That's also obviously wrong. The tree needs to be rebalanced, which is a lot of code, that's nowhere to be found. This can't be fixed. Start from scratch.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was under the impression that BSTs (as opposed to RB trees or similar) are not guaranteed to be balanced and so rebalancing after deletion isn't necessary.

Comment: Well, @MikeVine, in order to delete a non-leaf node, something needs to be rebalanced, or something needs to be done. But the shown code does absolutely nothing, whatsoever.

Comment: I guess I think of rebalancing as something which is done - after a delete or insertions - that _guarantees the tree remains balanced_. The delete doesn't need to do that - although I agree it does need to do a bunch more work and is wrong as written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you delete the node, but the parent of that node still points to it. So you are trying to print a deleted node.

You have to remember who was the parent of the node you delete and to update it to no longer point to it.

Many ways to do it, I personally would make `tmp` a double pointer if I was you but since your name is `newbie` here is a little easier to read solution:

```
cout << "\nElement to delete: " << val << " \n";
Node<T>* tmp = root;
Node<T>* parent = NULL;
while (tmp != NULL)
{
    if (val == tmp->data)
    {
        cout << "Element found: " << tmp->data << " \n";

        if (tmp->right_child == NULL && tmp->left_child == NULL)
        {
            if (parent == NULL) root = NULL;
            else {
                if (parent->right_child == tmp) {
                    parent->right_child = NULL;
                } else {
                    parent->left_child = NULL;
                }
            }
            delete tmp;
            size--;
        }

        break;
    }
    else if (val > tmp->data)
    {
        parent = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->right_child;
    }
    else if (val < root->data)
    {
        parent = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->left_child;
    }
}
```

Of course you have to add the handling for the case when node is not a leaf too, but it looks like you understand this.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it